# How do check for key value pair over multiple arrays and filter with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to filter data by key value pairs. I need to be able to check if a key value pair exists across multiple arrays.

I have some working code to count the number of objects containing a key value pair but run into problems when there are more that one array.

```js
var data = [{
    LastName: "Johnson",
    Id: 2222,
    specialties: [{
        Specialty: "Cardiology",
        BoardCertified: true,
        IsPrimary: true
      },
      {
        Specialty: "Pediatrics",
        BoardCertified: true,
        IsPrimary: true
      }
    ],
  },

  {
    LastName: "Hamilton",
    Id: 2332,
    specialties: [{
      Specialty: "Pediatrics",
      BoardCertified: true,
      IsPrimary: true
    }, ],
  }
]


var specialty = "Pediatrics";

var filtered = data.filter(function(item) {
  return item.specialties[0].Specialty == specialty;
});

console.log(filtered.length);
```

This counts the items with a key value pair of "Specialty: “Pediatrics"".

Right now this will only return "1" but I want it to return "2".

Is this possible?

**return item.specialties.Specialty == specialty;**     //does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure it will only appear once in each grouping, you can modify your filtering function:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(item){
     return item.specialties.some(item => item.Specialty === specialty);
)};
```

Or with two arrow functions:

```
var filtered = data.filter(item => 
      item.specialties.some(item =>
         item.Specialty === specialty)
   )
```